# Reputation loss as daily limit reached

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

I remember it being extensively discussed in pre-meta times, but I hope that someone could clarify that for me here as well.

Situation: I've 195 today

1. upvote then downvote leaves me with 198
2. downvote then upvote leaves me with 200

(no edits have been made in the mean time).

The question is what happens to that "excessive" rep? Will I ever get back those two points? If not, isn't it a bug?

Answer (score 9):

I think you *can* get them back if you get upvoted again before your first accepted answer. I've certainly seen that situation before, where you get 2 rep for the next vote. Once you're actually *over* 200 for the day, you won't get a downvote loss back - for instance, if you end up on 215 due to an accepted answer, then get a downvote, the only way of rising above 213 is to get another answer accepted.

Whether it's a "bug" or not depends on whether you believe the behaviour has been *designed* either way. My personal suspicion is that it falls into the category of "stuff which wasn't intentional but isn't serious enough to change."

EDIT: No, I don't believe a rep recalc will do anything to help you here. As I understand it, a rep recalc is effectively a matter of "rerunning history" but only including posts which haven't been deleted or votes that have been cancelled due to vote fraud etc. It doesn't change what happens in terms of the rep limit, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: By getting rep back I meant at the next recalculation, not from another vote.

Comment: I'm not sure the algorithm used for rep recalc, but it seems to be almost always against your favor.

Answer (score 2):

Those points are lost forever.

It is not a bug, is it by design. It was meant to limit the amount by which certain users (**cough**Jon Skeet**cough**) could run away from the rest of the pack. So, the rep is not deferred to another day, it is simply lost.

But, the very next day you have another fresh chance to earn 200 *new* rep points.