# Breaking Rep Limit - Possible?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

It seems that it is ever so slightly possible to break the reputation limit, or I am misunderstanding something. Here is what I think happened:

1. I hit a daily reputation limit from upvotes only. (+200)
2. I received a down vote. (+198)
3. I received another upvote (back to +200)
4. The existing downvote was *removed*, so I got credited +2

From my reputation tab:

[image]

So we see 277 rep. Answers don't count against your reputation limit, so if we factor those outwe do `277 - (15 *5)` = 202. So it looks like I got 202 points from upvotes.

Comment: This has happened to me at least 3 times. You only need to be rep-capped when the downvote is revoked. You don't need to be capped when it is initially cast.

Comment: [This guy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6138/reputation-loss-as-daily-limit-reached/6139#6139) has apparently experienced the same thing.

Comment: Go to [/reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation) and trigger a recalculation, the +2 will likely get removed due to the reputation cap. Never know though.

Comment: It will get removed due to a recalc I am like 99% sure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reputation tab is not something entirely trustworthy... When posts get deleted or downvotes reversed it can get out of sync with reality.

The reality you need to check against is the audit log at:

https://stackoverflow.com/reputation

This should show you that the extra 2 rep you have seen on the reputation tab have not in fact been awarded.

Comment: Yes, the recalc (I always forget about that) seems to have blown those two points away. I've experienced the odd behavior with deletes before, but not with a downvote getting removed.

Comment: Yep... the recalc follow what you see in the rep audit.

Comment: Is there a link to there anywhere on SO?

Comment: @Kevin - To where? The reputation audit? Not as far as I know.

Comment: @Kevin it's one of the [hidden features](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/hidden-features-of-stack-overflow) of Stack Overflow.. there are much more. Also note that [developers can see this page for other users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46673/rep-cap-kicking-in-a-little-too-early/46680#46680).

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd Thanks, I'll have to read about the other hidden features when I have a minute.